# Displaying views based on current index of items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am building a quiz app where I get the questions from an API. I have 2 views(called frontView and backView), and each of them have 1 image(called frontImageView and backImageView) and 4 buttons(but for now I only added 1 button for each view as frontAnswer1 and backAnswer1). **I am trying to change those views one after other, based on how many items in my _results array**

When make the call to get the JSON items, this is an example of what I get:

```
AccountId = 0;
        Answers =         (
            "a",
            "b",
            c,
            "d"
        );
        CategoryId = 2;
        CategoryName = "abc";
        CorrectAnswer = "b";
        Difficulty = 1;
        Id = 24;
        PicUrl = "http://someURL";
```

Then I loop through this json to get the answers and pic url:

```
 for (NSDictionary * itemDict in array) {
                         Item *myResponseItems = [[Item alloc] initWithDictionary:itemDict];
                         [tempArray addObject:myResponseItems];
                }

                            _results = tempArray;
```

Then I assign the objects to their appropriate places in my views like this:

//_JSONObjectsForTheFrontView and _JSONObjectForTheBackView  are class instance of my item class, where I parse the json objects.
//_results array contains all of my items that I want to display.

```
_JSONObjectsForTheFrontView = [_results objectAtIndex:0];
                            [_frontAnswerButton1 setTitle:[_JSONObjectsForTheFrontView.Answers objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 _frontImageView.image = _JSONObjectsForTheFrontView.image;

 _JSONObjectForTheBackView =[_results objectAtIndex:1];
                            [_backAnswer1 setTitle:[_JSONObjectForTheBackView.Answers objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            _backImageView.image =_JSONObjectForTheBackView.image;
```

So I am trying to create a structure, where I can show views based on my array count.
This is what I have so far:
GameView.h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) Item *JSONObjectsForTheFrontView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Item *JSONObjectForTheBackView;

@property (nonatomic,assign)NSInteger currentIndexInTheResultsArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger viewCount;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSIndexPath *CurrentIndexPathForTheResutsArray;
```

GameView.m
//_currentIndexInTheResultsArray is the integer where I keep store how many items i have.
//_viewCount is just an integer set to 0.
    _currentIndexInTheResultsArray = [_results count];
 NSLog(@"there are %ld , of items in the current index",(long)_currentIndexInTheResultsArray);

```
for (_viewCount = 0; _viewCount<_currentIndexInTheResultsArray;_viewCount++ ) {

if (_currentIndexInTheResultsArray %2 ==0) {

_JSONObjectsForTheFrontView = [_results objectAtIndex:_viewCount];

[_frontAnswer1 setTitle:[_JSONObjectsForTheFrontView.Answers objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

_frontImageView.image = _JSONObjectsForTheFrontView.image;
}
else if (_currentIndexInTheResultsArray %2 ==1)
{
 _JSONObjectForTheBackView =[_results objectAtIndex:_viewCount];

[_backAnswer1 setTitle:[_JSONObjectForTheBackView.Answers objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_backImageView.image =_JSONObjectForTheBackView.image;                            
 }
 }
```

When I run it. I get an empty view, in the first page, and the last question in the second page. 
If someone can help me with this, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: When you format your code properly, it makes it easier for others to understand, and therefore easier to get help.

Comment: @robmayoff, I added comments, sorry about that.

Comment: I figured out the what the problem is. Instead of a for loop, I need to increase the index inside the button click event and just but the views inside a setter.